# What happened to Journal of Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop, history

This journal appears to have went out of print over decade ago. When did it go out of print (I have looked online and do not access to an academic library)? Was it superseded by another journal of similar lineage?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about when a journal went out of print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOT:_Journal_of_Object_Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOT%3a_Journal_of_Object_Technology)) claims that it was replaced by the [Journal of Object Technology](http://www.jot.fm).  I do not see the articles from JOOP online, though, other than as lists of tables of contents.